# is there a practical difference between this two getters, in F#?

Tags: f#

I'm wondering about the two syntax for the getters:

```
type Direction =
    | Undefined
    | Buy
    | Sell

    member this.Symbol =
        match this with
        | Direction.Buy       -> '↑'
        | Direction.Sell      -> '↓'
        | Direction.Undefined -> '→'

    member this.Symbol2 with get() =
        match this with
        | Direction.Buy       -> '↑'
        | Direction.Sell      -> '↓'
        | Direction.Undefined -> '→'
```

Is there any practical difference between the first one and the second one?
The IL looks identical, but from the usage standpoint? is one preferred for any reason?

Answer (score 2):

They are identical, yes. In general, prefer the first one. The reason why the second one exists is if you have some special logic to do  that isn't just grabbing a value. It's more flexible, but more syntax.

Comment: How does the second version  support special logic that you couldn’t do with the first one?

Comment: You can write stupid nonsense like this, of course! https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgPgLgngBwKYAIAiBLATkgxjDAewDsUBeAWACgVaUoUBVYgEyTA2KRervpQBCAVzi86DAMpJgwamNoBbJAoBGSLChgALDBAB0EuKsLBy8vigUBDGLi2adEFAHcM283waYc+IsT3CcBa0ALQAfCgA5ICJhJEe4ujYeAQkBtKmFuFRgMmEcTTB/N7JfnrMbBxcLChZkYBJhHnmSqrqDroGRiomAEwubvYA5kgwKAAeZvnBwEMoLNjjBRbWtvbaur3uEwuFSb6pgQU1sfHBXjsp/lIywTW5xxanPuelrOyc3NURdXkLsxoA1KMgA=

Comment: Oh, that’s interesting. So then you invoke it like a method, with an argument. I didn’t realize that was possible for a getter. Thanks.

Comment: I would argue about "stupid nonsense". It's called `indexed property` (ecma 335) or `parameterful property` (clr via c#), have [good documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/indexed-properties) and in my opinion is highly underestimated

Comment: I'm not referring to indexed properties. I'm referring to the ability to write nonsense code!